# Rails - how to send string as a query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table with columns that are numbered (e.g. Group1, Group2, Group 3). I'd like write a loop that queries the table while grouping on a different Group each time (e.g. first iteration groups on Group1, second iteration groups on Group2 etc.). I'm aware of the send method but I'm having trouble adapting it to Rails query methods like .where and .group.

I'm looking for something along the lines of:

```
group = "Group1"
Table.send("group(:#{group})")
```

Is this possible? Do I just have the wrong syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To strictly answer your question, `#send` takes a symbol that represents a method name, followed by any parameters. So what you want is:

```rb
Table.send(:group, 'Group1')
```

Having said that, resorting to `#send` seems unnecessary. Could you not just do something like:

```rb
groups = %i[group1 group2 group3]
groups.each do |g|
  Table.where(...).group(g)  # or whatever
end
```